# spring data - how to filter users of a particular userProfile by userProfileType?

Tags: spring-data

My `User` entity follows:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;

    // non relevant attributes

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "user2userProfile",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userProfileId"))
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfileSet;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The `UserProfile` entity follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userProfile")
public class UserProfile {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "type", length = 15, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

    // constructors, getter and setter
}
```

The `UserProfileType` enum is

```
public enum UserProfileType {

    USER("USER"),
    READER("READER"),
    WRITER("WRITER"),
    ADMIN("ADMIN");

// constructor and getter
}
```

My `UserJpaRepository` is:

```
public interface UserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    // non relevant code

    List<User> findAllByUserProfileType(UserProfileType userProfileType);
}
```

The way it stands now, I get the following error message on the console:

`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property userProfileType found for type User!`

What is the correct declaration on `UserJpaRepository` to get a list of users that have a specific UserProfileType (i.e. a list of all users that have a UserProfile of type READER)?

Comment: try type instead of userProfileType

Comment: did not work, but I managed to implement a different method on the service the calls the repository and filtered down from the findAll() Users method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you need to have a many to many relationship from your user to your user profile.
So if we would correct that to a many to one relationship like:

in User:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserProfile> profiles;
```

in UserProfile:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

you could just setup a search by `String type` in your UserProfileRepository:

```
List<UserProfile> findAllByType(String type);
```

If you now iterate the List you get, you can get all users with a certain UserProfileType:

```
List<User> users = userProfileRepository.findAllByType(UserProfileType.USER.toString()).stream().map(profile -> profile.getUser()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```